# Nil value for array in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, null

I feel like a moron asking this, but since I'm a new to developing, and I've been sitting here for an hour making something so simple work, I need to ask.

I want to show each Widget, but I keeping getting:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

I tried using <%= debug @widgets %> and <%= @widgets.inspect %>, but nothing shows in my command prompt or browser.

I was trying to copy the each do statement on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

In my controller, called Pages Controller, I have:

```
def widgets_to_show
  @widgets = Widget.all
end
```

In my view (pages#widgets_to_show), I have:

```
<% @widgets.each do |widget| %>
  <%= widget.title %>
<% end %>
```

- I have a widget model
- I also have values in the widgets table
- and I have a title field, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

I'm trying to display it on a page that uses the High Voltage gem (https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you access them from `rails console` (`rails c`)?

Comment: OK, dumb question.  Once I get into the console, what do I type after irb prompt (windows user)

Comment: `Widget.all` :) Never underestimate the power of the [repl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). It amazes me that people can live without it.

Comment: @yellowreign don't do this in `irb`, do this in `rails console`. If you do it in `irb` your rails environment wont be loaded so it wont know what `Widget` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DaveNewton suggested try accessing the widget from your **console** (not irb). Do the following from your terminal

```
# from your rails project dir
$ rails c
$ w = Widgets.all
$ puts w
$ w.each { |n| puts n.title }
```

If all of that works then we need more info to figure out what the problem is.

**Edit:**

My guess is that it has something to do with using high voltage on the same page. It's a gem for creating **static** pages so maybe that's interfering with showing your widgets - since what you're doing is something **dynamic**.

Comment: hi @Dty, thanks for the answer.  After puts W, I get: #<Widget:0x7cf96e0> four times (with dift hex codes) which matches the four entries in the table, then it concludes with => nil.  For the last step it gives the four titles for those Widgets

Comment: oh, sorry.  and then the last step concludes with: => [#<Widget id:1.....>].  It returns the first record after => (after w.each)

Comment: The `puts w` line concludes with a nil because that's what `puts` returns. I edited my answer, I think it has to do with high voltage. Try removing that and reload the page.